# c# Interop.excel Range.formula error with VLOOKUP

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm developing with VS 2015 c#, trying to put a formula inside a cell.
the formula is:

```
articoli[contatorerighe, 3] = @"=CERCA.VERT(D" + (contatorerighe + cellaIniziale).ToString()+";'[Listino.xlsx]Listino'!A3:C"+ totrighe.ToString()+ ";3)";
```

If I put the formula in excel it works, but when I try to call

```
artRange.set_Value(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, articoli);
artRange.Formula = artRange.Value;
```

an exception occur with an error : Eccezione da HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

I tried to put "VLOOKUP" and not "CERCA.VERT" that is my language but no result.
I put the complete path of file but it puts double backslash in the string like "c:\aaaa\bbbb...." is it right?

I'm going mad with this. Help
thank you.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE : I found the solution at the problem (a part of the solution).
The method to call is :

```
artRange.FormulaR1C1Local = artRange.Value;
```

that translate formulas in your excel country language.
It works good and it's not slow.
The only thing i have to try is making the procedure not asking me the path of file for VLOOKUP (CERCA.VERT).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like :

```
YourSheet.Cells.Formula = string.Format("your formula here");
```

or just

```
YourSheet.Cells.Formula = "your formula here";
```

Not sure if this will help, but hopefully it will !

Comment: FormulaLocal was the solution!